# How can I upload a Build Artifact to someplace that's web-accessible?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been using the `GitHubRelease@0` task to host individual releases on Github, but I'm switching to continuous releases, and want to be able to upload them somewhere else that doesn't litter up my Github Releases page; somewhere that's publicly accessible and possibly even free.  (I'm not sure if [Azure Artifacts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/artifacts/) is appropriate for this; I'm open to any hosting where it's easy to avoid incurring high costs.)

I've spotted the `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` task, but haven't found any hints as to whether that's relevant, and certainly none about how to discover a public URL for a published artifact.

I want to be able to know the published artifacts' URLs from within my Build Pipeline, so that I can embed them into a homebrew ruby formula.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can upload to an artifacts feed as a universal package. Public artifact feeds are in preview.

Comment: @DanielMann I've looked into universal packages and public artifact feeds, but can't make heads or tails of them, and also unclear on whether it satisfies my need for the public urls to the published files within the Azure build pipeline.